# Is there an easy method to create an 8 sided polygon with different length sides

Tags: objects

Just wondering what method how to create an 8 sided polygon with different length sides and opposite sides the same length as per the following 'drawing' (my attempt using extrude vertices).
I also tried starting with an 8 sided cylinder mesh with Z axis scaled to 0 and then attempt to drag the edges.
I also tried adding two intersecting triangular planes (24 X 7  and 21 X 12 Joined and all transforms) but could not work out how to FILL 4 the missing triangular areas (see dotted line in second image). Tried selecting a vertice and then extrude on both the X and Y axis but could not get that to work.

**Side lengths** are only **approximate** and obtained from a satellite image.

And the distance between sides marked 12 would be about 21 and than the distance between sides marked 7 about 24.

[image]

[image]

Here is a screen shot from Google Earth showing one side of the decking area I wanted to model. NO angles (to my knowledge) are obtainable from Google Earth and dimensions are approximate.

[image]

My method of adding 3 sided cylinder and then snapping edges of corners. Should I add this as 'answer your own question'?

[image]

Comment: With the provided measurements, the "corners" would actually come out as 9.22 units. If that satisfies your needs, I can give you a quick run down of the process

Comment: Thanks. Don't know what you mean by corners "coming out as 9.22 units" HOWEVER the area covered, the angles and dimensions don't need to be exact so long as they are near to the units I gave in the first image and the distance between the 12 meter sides and the 7 meter sides are near to the units I gave.

Comment: Question is answered but to be clear in my comment: "diagonals"  instead of "corners" would be a bit more accurate. You have sides with 12, 10 and 7 units. but with your provided distances of 21 and 24, the 10 unit edge would be 9.22 units.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one's just a scaled octagon. Bring up an 8-sided mesh-circle, rotate by 22.5° to align to XY, and hit <kbd>S</kbd>, drag a little, then enter the appropriate divisions numerically.

[image]

As you can see (before the illustrated move)  by enabling the Edit Mode 'Edge Length' overlay, or, as here, using the shipped 'MeasureIt' add-on for display, the default radius 1 octagon has side-length 0.7654, so your desired X and Y edge-lengths have to be divided through by that.

You could, if you wanted, <kbd>F</kbd> join some vertices on opposite sides, and constrain to those lengths instead, or as well, by scaling only selected opposite sides, orthogonally to their direction.

Comment: Thanks Robin. Using your method I got the sides to be 12.2m 7.19m and 10m which is very close and close enough to the dimensions I measured using Google Earth.

Comment: @JohnArnold  This method is actually under-constrained, and so a bit 'lucky'. If you want to get _all_ measurements,  including diameters, repeat in a similar way, scaling only selected opposite edges.

Answer (score 6):

The information you provide only says that the diagonal line builds an orthogonal triangle where the hypotenuse has a length of 10 m. This alone does not say anything about the adjacent angles or the lengths of the catheti (well, you give approx values, but let's say the 7, 10 and 12 m are the only exact things we know for the sake of this explanation, for something using the approx values see second method below). This way, your octagon can have many different shapes (well, maybe apart from the two extreme variations where it is a simple rectangle):

[image: animated octagon]

#### First method: No calculations - using a 45° angle

But let's pretend you want the diagonal edge have an angle of 45°. You could calculate the length of a cathetus (both have the same length in this triangle), but that's not necessary for constructing it in Blender:

1. Add a plane, this is by default 2 × 2 m. Go into *Edit Mode* and select the face, then scale it by a factor of 5 with <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd>.
2. Now the edges are 10 m long. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for the *Face* menu and choose *Poke Faces*.

   [image: poke faces]
3. Now the plane consists of four triangles with a center point. From the top view with all faces selected rotate by 45° with <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>45</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd>.

   [image: rotate plane]
4. Now delete all faces except for one, e.g. the one on the top left. Select it and move it away from the origin, in case of the top left triangle -6 m on the X and 3.5 m on Y with <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>-6</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd> and <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>3.5</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd>.

   [image: move triangle]
5. Now select the vertical edge on the right and extrude it 6 m in X direction with <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd>, afterwards select both horizontal edges at the bottom and extrude them -3.5 m in Y direction with <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>-3.5</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd>.

   [image: extrude edges]
6. Now you can add a *Mirror* modifier and enable X and Y as axes for mirroring.

   [image: mirroring]

#### Second method: Knowing a target height/width, calculating the rest

(*Okay, this is a bit to show off the math geek in me. For an easier way, look for the third method at the end.*) Now let's say you know the overall height should be 23 m, then it's easy to calculate that the vertical height of that small orthogonal triangle must be

$$\frac{(23-7)}{2}=8\text{ m}$$

the longest diagonal side is 10 m and the remaining question is, how much is the small horizontal edge at the bottom - and from that how wide is the complete shape?

[image: problem overview]

Thanks to mathematics, since we know two edges of the triangle and the angle opposite of the longer edge we can calculate the missing edge length. Taking a look at the schematics below, we have the edges $a$ and $b$ as well as the angle $\beta$.

[image: triangle schematics]

To find $c$ we first have to determine the other angles $\alpha$ and $\gamma$. For $\alpha$ applies

$$\sin \alpha=\frac{a\cdot \sin \beta}{b} \iff \alpha=\arcsin \left(\frac{a\cdot \sin \beta}{b}\right)$$

With $\beta = 90° \implies \sin \beta = 1$ this leaves us

$$\alpha=\arcsin \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$$

Inserting the lengths $a=8$ and $b=10$ in the formula:

$$\alpha=\arcsin \left(\frac{8}{10}\right)=\arcsin (0.8) \approx 53.13°$$

The remaining angle $\gamma$ follows from the sum of internal angles in a triangle, which is 180°:

$$\gamma = 180° - (\alpha + \beta) \implies \gamma \approx 180° - (53.13°+90°)=36.87°$$

Now that we have all angles we can calculate the missing edge $c$ with this formula:

$$c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2-2\cdot a \cdot b \cdot\sin \gamma}$$

Entering the values computed before (taking the exact angles instead of the rounded ones) this gives us

$$c=\sqrt{64+100-\left(160 \cdot\sin \gamma\right)}=\sqrt{164-128}=\sqrt{36} = 6$$

So the bottom edge of the triangle is 6 m. Knowing that the top and bottom vertical edges of the octagon are 12 m wide this gives us an overall width of the octagon shape of

$$(6\text{ m}\cdot2)+12\text{ m}=24\text{ m}$$

[image: octagon final]

In the above formulas the values for width or height of the triangle are interchangeable, meaning it does not matter if you know what the overall height or width of the octagon should be, you can calculate the remaining values with the same formulas.

At last, constructing the octagon with the found values:

1. Add a plane, set the dimensions to X = 12 m, Y = 23 m. Add another plane, set the dimensions to X = 24 m, Y = 7 m.

   [image: add planes]
2. Select both and join them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. Apply the scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply* > *Scale*. Now <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode* and select all with <kbd>A</kbd>.
3. Enable the *Auto Merge* function and also the option *Split Edges & Faces*.

   [image: auto merge]
4. With all vertices selected, start moving them by pressing <kbd>G</kbd> but enter the number <kbd>0</kbd> to make sure they do not move at all (but do not abort the move tool). After entering the value press <kbd>Return</kbd> or left-click to confirm the action.
5. Thanks to *Auto Merge* and the *Split...* option, the two faces are now merged together and the intersections split in separate faces. Remember to turn off *Auto Merge* as you might accidentally mess up other geometry later.

   You can now select three vertices and press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill the space between them with a new triangle face. Repeat that for the other sides.

   [image: fill the gaps]

#### Third method: The Pythagorean theorem

One theorem that almost everybody knows for orthogonal triangles:

$$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$$

where $a$ and $b$ are the catheti and $c$ is the hypotenuse:

[image: pythagorean theorem]

So let's say we have the same conditions as before, then in the above schematics we have $c = 10 \text{ m}$ and $b = 8 \text{ m}$ and want to know $a$. From the theorem we can deduct $a$ like this:

$$\begin{align} a^2 + b^2 = c^2 &\iff a^2 = c^2 - b^2 \\ &\iff a = \sqrt{c^2 - b^2} \end{align}$$

Inserting the values for $b$ and $c$ we get:

$$\begin{align} a &= \sqrt{10^2 - 8^2} \\ &= \sqrt{100 - 64} \\ &= \sqrt{36} \\ &= 6\end{align}$$

as before of course, only much quicker ;) The construction would be the same as described above.

**Just a final suggestion:** I don't know how carved in stone the 7 m dimension is, but if you make it 8 m the octagon will have an aspect ratio of 1:1 with 24 × 24 m.

Comment: This one's making me feel _very_ , _very_ guilty... :D

Comment: @RobinBetts But why? I feel guilty that I didn't add the third and simplest method earlier :D

Comment: Thanks Gordon. You have put a huge effort into your response and methods. Once again the dimensions are only approximate and obtained from a Google Earth satellite view. I just found out that I need to add a comment under your response instead of at the bottom for you to get notified - sorry. I also worked out that I could 'fill in' the triangular areas by adding a 3 sided cylinder and then with snap edge turned on and selecting the edges of the 'triangle' and dragging them to the appropriate edge on the intersecting rectangle however someone said 'use geometric nodes' not sure what he meant.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the multitude of wonderful answers, here is the *Geometry Nodes* version:

[image]

Just connect two grids with the desired dimensions, and then add the Node `Convex Hull`.

The advantage of this solution is that it is procedural.

Comment: Thanks for the extra methods described and the obvious time you have taken to type up the methods which I appreciate as it added to my knowledge. I will try these out however even though they are more accurate in keeping to the dimensions I indicated (but also stated that they were approximate and taken from a Google Earth satellite image)  they look more complicated than Robin's method.  And once again I am only trying to close replicate a satellite image where there are no angles and dimensions are only approximate (I will add a screen shot from Google)  Thanks again Gordon and quellenform.

Comment: Hey guys. I was trying to implement Gordon's second method and after getting a little 'lost' came up with a method which also works.  I added a mesh cylinder and gave it 3 sides (triangle) then moved it into the 'top left' of the areas between the 2 mesh cubes. I then set 'snap edge on', selected the nearest corner of the triangle to the appropriate edge on the intersecting mesh cubes. Repeated for the other two. Then Joined all the added 'triangles' to the intersecting mesh cubes. There seems to be so many ways of achieving things in Blender - see image above. And your opinions of my method?

Comment: @JohnArnold Well, I can't say much about that, except: use *Geometry Nodes* ;-) ...that is the easiest/flexible solution. If you want to notify Gordon, you would have to write your comment under his answer.

Comment: Thanks quellenform. I should have noticed before that I can add a response under someone's method and not just at the bottom of the thread. Thanks for alerting me to that. Not sure if the methods suggested are easier than my method though although maybe not as flexible.